# How to add anchor links when links as well sections are populated using PageableListView? How will I get the "id" to which my link should point to?

Tags: java, html, wicket-6

Editing the question to provide the code.

HTML:-

```
<a href=""><div wicket:id="awardLink_"></div></a>
```

JAVA:

final   PageableListView awardLinksList = new PageableListView("awardLinksList_",
                AwardList, 10) {

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unchecked", "unchecked" })
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            final BLL_Docs StkList = (BLL_Docs) item
                    .getModelObject();  
            item.add(new Label("awardLink_",StkList.getAwardName()==null?"NA":StkList.getAwardName()));             
            }

    };
```

The above code will provide 4-5 list of awards which will be generated using pageablelistview
Ex:Bharat Ratna, Padma Bhushan, Padma Vibhushan.

Description of each award will be generated through

HTML:-

```
<div wicket:id="lblFarmerBio" class="control-label2"></div>
```

JAVA:

final
        PageableListView awdDisplay = new PageableListView("listView_",
                ImgList, 10) {

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @SuppressWarnings({ "serial", "unchecked", "unchecked" })
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
            final BLL_Docs StkList = (BLL_Docs) item
                    .getModelObject();              

            item.add(new Label("lblFarmerBio",StkList.getFarmerBio()==null?"NA":StkList.getFarmerBio()));               

            }

    };
```

When I click on link Bharat Ratna, it should focus on the part which provided description of Bharat Ratna.

Comment: Could you share your code so that easy to sorted out

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not providing any code snippet con't able to produce desired output.

There are some suggestion following :

What you need is `onclick` the link you should point to the section for that

```
<a href="#section1" wicket:id="sectionLink">Go my section  div</a>

 <div id="section1" wicket:id="section"> Focus here on click with the respected link id reference</div>
```

Java

```
   // It just reference object
        private class DataObject implements Serializable{
                private String link;
                private String section;
        // getter & setter , constructor
        }


     List<DataObject> dataObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
            dataObjectList.add(new DataObject("section1","Section1 with a description"));
    dataObjectList.add(new DataObject("section2","Section2  with a description"));
    dataObjectList.add(new DataObject("section3","Section3  with a description"));
    dataObjectList.add(new DataObject("section4","Section4  with a description"));

            ListView<DataObject> pageableListView = new PageableListView("Lists",dataObjectList,20) {
                @Override
                protected void populateItem(ListItem listItem) {
                    DataObject dataObject = (DataObject) listItem.getModelObject();
                    //WebComponent or WebMarkupContainer either you can use
                    WebMarkupContainer sectionLink = new WebMarkupContainer("sectionLink");
                    sectionLink.add(new AttributeModifier("href","#"+dataObject.getLink()));
                    listItem.add(sectionLink);
                    Label sectionPart = new Label("section",dataObject.getSection());
                     sectionPart.add(new AttributeModifier("id",listItem.getIndex()));
                    listItem.add(sectionPart);

                }
            };
            add(pageableListView);
```

Comment: <a href=""><div wicket:id="awardLink_"></div></a> will provide 4-5list of awards and description of each award is will be generated through <div wicket:id="lblFarmerBio" class="control-label2"></div>

Comment: So you have different list right ? why are you using label instead of link

Comment: Two lists, one for name of award and the other one for the description of award. I've edited the question, you'll get better idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since You need more information I have added one more answer:

```
//I guess you model like this 
public class BLL_Docs implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private String awardName;
    private String awardinfo;

    public BLL_Docs(Integer id, String awardName, String awardinfo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.awardName = awardName;
        this.awardinfo = awardinfo;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAwardName() {
        return awardName;
    }

    public void setAwardName(String awardName) {
        this.awardName = awardName;
    }

    public String getAwardinfo() {
        return awardinfo;
    }

    public void setAwardinfo(String awardinfo) {
        this.awardinfo = awardinfo;
    }
}
```

Html page

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Apache Wicket Quickstart</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:regular,bold' rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body>


<wicket:container wicket:id="awardList">
<a  wicket:id="awardNameLink"><label wicket:id="awardName"></label></a><br>
</wicket:container>


<wicket:container wicket:id="awardDescriptionList">
<p wicket:id="description"></p>
</wicket:container>



</body>
</html>
```

Java Page:

```
//Im considering your object like this
        List<BLL_Docs> awardList = new ArrayList<>();
        BLL_Docs bll_docs1 = new BLL_Docs(1, "Bharat Ratna", "The Bharat Ratna is the highest civilian award of the Republic of India.");
        BLL_Docs bll_docs2 = new BLL_Docs(2, "Padma Bhushan", "The Padma Bhushan is the highest civilian award of the Republic of India.");
        BLL_Docs bll_docs3 = new BLL_Docs(3, "Padma Vibhushan", "The Padma Vibhushan is the highest civilian award of the Republic of India.");

        awardList.add(bll_docs1);
        awardList.add(bll_docs2);
        awardList.add(bll_docs3);


        PageableListView<BLL_Docs> awardLinksList = new PageableListView("awardList", awardList, 10) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                BLL_Docs bll_docs = (BLL_Docs) item.getModelObject();
                Link awardNameLink = new Link("awardNameLink") {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick() {
                    }
                };
                awardNameLink.add(new AttributeModifier("href","#"+bll_docs.getAwardName()));
                 Label awardName = new Label("awardName" ,bll_docs.getAwardName());
                awardNameLink.add(awardName);
                item.add(awardNameLink);
            }
        };


        PageableListView<BLL_Docs> describtionList = new PageableListView("awardDescriptionList", awardList, 10) {

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
                BLL_Docs bll_docs = (BLL_Docs) item.getModelObject();
                Label description = new Label("description",bll_docs.getAwardinfo());
                description.add(new AttributeModifier("id",bll_docs.getAwardName()));
                item.add(description);
            }
        };
         add(describtionList);
        add(awardLinksList);
    }
```

I have successfully tested this working fine.While testing add more description and test .

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out.